# RegEx for use with fail2ban on nginx with wordpress and custom log format

Tags: regex, wordpress, nginx, logfile, fail2ban

I need to block certain requests with fail2ban based on a custom logfile-format for an nginx webserver access.log.

The offending lines which should match are in **access.log** and look like this:

```
06/Oct/2016:18:44:29 +0200 191.96.249.53 - - mydomain.com "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)" "-"
06/Oct/2016:18:44:29 +0200 191.96.249.53 - - mydomain.com "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)" "-"
06/Oct/2016:18:44:29 +0200 191.96.249.53 - - mydomain.com "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)" "-"
```

My **fail2ban** configuration wordpress-xmlrpc.conf with RegEx:

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST>.*POST .*.(*wp-login\.php|*xmlrpc\.php).*.(403|499)*
ignoreregex =
```

The jail is running, but never finds the offending lines:

Status for the jail: wordpress-xmlrpc (simplified):
- File list:        /var/log/nginx/access.log
- Currently failed: 0
- Total failed:     0
- Currently banned: 0
- Total banned:     0

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how your regex currently works: [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ofi2Sq/1)

I would change it to:

```
^.*POST .*(wp-login|xmlrpc)\.php.*(403|499)*
```

Comment: ... but this is not addressing the problem. The <host> is needed to work, see fail2ban doc:[link](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8)`In every line of failregex, the part that matches the host name or IP address must be wrapped in a (?P<host> ... ) sandwich. This is a Python-specific regex extension that assigns the contents of the match to the name <host>. The <host> tag is how you tell fail2ban which host was connecting, so it has to be present in every line of failregex.`<Host> is an alias fort this.

Comment: this seems to work. I checked it with two lines from access.log using 

fail2ban-regex -v --print-all-missed 

and both lines match! thx! 

nevertheless I don't get any IPs banned, although there is lines on access.log, service was restarted and don't see any errors on fail2ban.log (log level 4)